# sed to replace value for a key in a json object

Tags: json, regex, sed, replace

**What am I trying to do?**

Given a file of json events. I want to locate specific events by keyword and then replace the value of key in that event with "".
This must be done with sed (Splunk forwarding issue.. I wont bore you with the details).

**Example Event**

```
{
  "message":"we have a response from SomeService",
  "other":"some stuff",
  "other2":"some other stuff",
  "xml":"<Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:awsse=\"http://xml.chicken.com/2010/06/Session_v3\" xmlns:wsa=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\"><Header><To>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</To><From><Address>..... AND SO ON BIG GIANT NASTEY XML",
  "other3":"even more stuff"
}
```

**Desired outcome**

```
{
  "message":"we have a response from SomeService",
  "other":"some stuff",
  "other2":"some other stuff",
  "xml":"",
  "other3":"even more stuff"
}
```

**What have I tried?**
I can isolate the events and replace a key no problem. I am struggling with a regex to replace the *value* of a key in the json.

```
cat test.json | sed '/"we have a response from SomeService"/ s/other2/chicken/'
```

Thansk for you help!

Comment: No, they are not. The whole json event is one line.

Comment: json is the same type of grammar as html, and we all know how well [that works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: `s/other2":"[^"]*",/other2":"newValue",/` ??   With everything on one line the greedy `.*` is going to burn you, so use `[^"]*` which means any number of non-doublequote chars.

Comment: You might try this `cat test.json | sed '/"xml":/ s/"xml":[^,]*/"xml":""/'` :)

Comment: Paul - this works great do you want to post it as an answer so I can green check mark it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*copy from comment*

You might try this

```
cat test.json | sed '/"xml":/ s/"xml":[^,]*/"xml":""/'
```

`[^,]*` will match everything until `,` being find.